# Задать корневой каталог при подключении по ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

При подключении к сайту по ssh мы попадаем в корневой каталог. Где и что прописать чтоб при подключении *ssh user@ip.host -p 22* я попадал не в **/home/user/** , а в **/home/user/var/www/** ?

Comment: в заголовке один вопрос, а в теле вопроса — совсем другой. и тот, что в заголовке, несколько туманен: что именно вы подразумеваете в данном случае под термином «корневой каталог»? невозможность обращения к файлам/каталогам за пределами данного? тогда см. `$ man sshd_config`, секция `chrootdirectory`. но это вряд ли вам подойдёт в виду накладываемых ограничений.

Comment: При заходе **только по ssh** через стандартный порт (-p 22) или при любом другом входе (скажем, с локальной консоли) тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По теме **заголовка** вопроса.

Использование ssh с логином в минимальное изолированное chroot окружение.

## Установка сервера rsync+chroot+ssh

**Установите необходимые пакеты:**

```
apt-get install rsync rssh patch
```

**Настройка chroot:**

```
chmod u+s /usr/lib/rssh/rssh_chroot_helper
mkdir -p /var/lib/rsync_chroot/var/lib/rsync_chroot
ln -s ../../../home /var/lib/rsync_chroot/var/lib/rsync_chroot/home
mkdir -p /var/lib/rsync_chroot/{dev,etc,lib64,lib/x86_64-linux-gnu,usr/bin,home}
mknod -m 666 /var/lib/rsync_chroot/dev/null c 1 3
mknod -m 666 /var/lib/rsync_chroot/dev/zero c 1 5
ln -s /run/systemd/journal/dev-log /var/lib/rsync_chroot/dev/log
cp -r /etc/{ld.so.conf.d,ld.so.cache,ld.so.conf,nsswitch.conf} /var/lib/rsync_chroot/etc/
cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/{libattr.so.1,libacl.so.1,libpopt.so.0,libc.so.6} /var/lib/rsync_chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /var/lib/rsync_chroot/lib64/
cp /usr/sbin/nologin /usr/bin/{rssh,rsync} /var/lib/rsync_chroot/usr/bin/

echo "13c13
< allowrsync
---
> #allowrsync
17c17
< umask = 022
---
> umask = 022
23c23
< chrootpath = /var/lib/rsync_chroot
---
> # chrootpath = /usr/local/chroot
" | patch -R /etc/rssh.conf
```

**Настройка пользователя для синхронизации:**

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --home /var/lib/rsync_chroot/home/repository --shell /usr/bin/rssh --group --disabled-password repository
mkdir -p /var/lib/rsync_chroot/home/repository/.ssh
chown repository:repository /var/lib/rsync_chroot/home/repository
chmod 0750 /var/lib/rsync_chroot/home/repository
cat > /var/lib/rsync_chroot/home/repository/.ssh/authorized_keys
  no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB ... user@host
```

**Отправка данных:**

```
rsync -rlHpti --del --delete-excluded ./data_dir/ repository@hostname:~/data
```

Comment: чтобы вот этого всего не городить, освойте, наконец, скрипт rrsync (restircted rsync), входящий в пакет rsync. и, да, ваш ответ не отвечает даже на то, что написано в заголовке. хотя автору вопроса, быть может, это и подойдёт (не ваш громоздкий вариант, а использование rrsync, конечно).

Comment: Согласен, что ответ не совсем в тему вопроса. По `rrsync` - на момент написания этого скрипта `rrsync` содержал трудно устранимые проблемы с безопасностью (выход за пределы окружения). Представленное решение выглядело безопаснее. Возможно, с тех пор, ситуация с `rrsync` улучшилась.

Comment: если вы про [этот тикет](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11879), так использование опции --safe-links было предложено (почти) сразу же, а в январе этого года добавили ещё и принудительную проверку на «две точки» ([commit a0274c0](https://git.samba.org/rsync.git/?p=rsync.git;a=commit;h=a0274c08b5b561c489046e835063f1e384bedd9c)). т.е. это не «трудноустранимая проблема». что же вы тогда подразумеваете?

Comment: Судя по репозиторию, скрипт впервые появился в 2011г. Тикеты того времени, возможно, остались в архиве. В понедельник попробую найти информацию о том, чем мы руководствовались, когда выбирали именно это решение. Если эта информация интересна и кому-нибудь будет полезна.

Answer (score 0):

добавьте команду

```
cd /нужный/каталог
```

в конец файла, интерпретируемого программой, выполняющей роль оболочки (*shell*), при запуске интерактивной сессии.

имя файла смотрите в документации к этой программе.

например, для программы

- *bash* это `~/.bashrc`
- *zsh* это `~/.zshrc`
- *dash* это `~/.profile`